# Key repeat delay and key repeat rate

Tags: vb.net, keyboard, key

How do I (programmatically) find out the key repeat delay and key repeat rate for a system?

A solution that works on any/all .Net capable platforms would be ideal, but the key target OSes would be XP, Vista, and 7.

Comment: Note to anyone who uses this, please make sure to read the MSDN documentation on them, they do not return seconds, milliseconds, etc.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.keyboarddelay.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.keyboardspeed%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's available in the SystemInformation.KeyboardDelay and KeyboardSpeed properties on all your listed operating systems.